# Новый проект в django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста! Пользуюсь Pycharm-ом начал новый проект когда запускаю проект то в браузере открывается предыдущий проект т.е. то что я делал до этого...подскажите пожалуйста как это можно перенастроить?

Comment: Когда работаете с Djangi лучше делайте виртуальную среду

Comment: в том то и дело что делал

Comment: Возможно вы ошибочно активировали старую среду?

Comment: Какой сервер вы используете? 
Посмотрите его настройки, аргументы запуска и т.д.

если вы используете python manage.py runserver то убедитесь что делаете это из каталога с новым проектом.